# Passing variable to shell from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I want to pass variable from python to shell script. My code looks like below.

```
Object_Id=12
Class_Name='My_Class'
Folder_Path='/My_Folder'

output=subprocess.check_output(['./execute.sh, 'Object_Id', 'Class_Name', "shell=True"])
print(output)
```

The execute.sh script is just simple echo statement

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

the output is

```
 Object_Id 
 Class_Name
```

The script is getting the args as literal strings but I want to get the value of the variable instead.

Comment: Could you state what is the difference between passing variable and getting args?
If you want to pass variable bash `export` might be your call.
You can always make code like:
`OBJECT_ID=$1; CLASS_NAME=$2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `check_output` call needs to pass the command and its arguments as a `list` or `str` separate from arguments to the `check_output` API itself. You shouldn't pass the *names* of your variables (your command has no idea what `Object_Id` means after all, and couldn't reach back into the Python process to identify if even if it understood), but rather the variables themselves (and your quotes are mismatched and need fixing). Really, you don't need `shell=True` here at all, so you can just do:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['./execute.sh', str(Object_Id), Class_Name])
```

If `shell=True` is important for some reason, you can do it by passing the string representing the shell command:

```
import shlex
output = subprocess.check_output('./execute.sh {} {}'.format(shlex.quote(Object_Id), shlex.quote(Class_Name)),
                                 shell=True)
```

Note that `shell=True` is a separate argument to `check_output`, *not* part of the command itself (the first positional argument).

Comment: I am rookie in python but first one is giving me exec format error ....I had tried this earlier only...and the second one is telling quote is missing in shlex module, i am using 2.7 python

Comment: @SubrataFouzdar: Why did you tag the question `python-3.x` when you're using Python 2.7?!? In any event, did you make sure to wrap `Object_Id` in `str()` (the non-shell variant must pass a `list` of `str`)? For the second version, if you know for sure that `Object_Id` and `Class_Name` contain strings that don't have whitespace or shell metacharacters in them, you can omit `shlex.quote`. Or just switch to Python 3; learning the old version of the language is needlessly handicapping yourself. Only use Python 2 when maintaining legacy code.

Comment: output = subprocess.check_output('./execute.sh {} {}'.format((Object_Id), (Class_Name)),shell=True)   --used this , regarding tagging of python 3.0 my apology

Answer (score -1):

it looks like it's taking the args as strings instead of the variable because you are enclosing it with `''` removing them should fix it